# Javascript Select on native N:N relationship entity crm 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Does anybody know how to query an N:N relationship entity in CRM 2011?

I am using the library CrmRestKit and I would like to select my relationship entity xxxx_relation_nn_entity1_entity2.

Is there a way to know what fields are contained in this entity so I can query it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a couple of ways you could do this, I havnt used the CrmRestKit but I'll assume this lets you issue all the same calls as if you were not using it.

You could issue a FetchXml query, [Markus Blog](http://markuserlandsson.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/using-fetch-xml-to-get-data-from-javascript/) has an example of how to do this.

You can use the Stunnware Tools 4.0 to help with the FetchXml. [Stunnware > Products > Stunnware Tools 4.0](http://www.stunnware.com/).

Or you could also use an OData call, [Lakshman](http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/retrieve-multiple-using-odata-in-crm-2011/) has an example of how to do this, he also includes a link to an OData designer.

The Msdn also has some more information on this: [Data Access Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584#BKMK_DataAccessUsingJavaScript).

Hope that helps